# how to clear child window reference stored in parent application when child window is closed?

Tags: python, events, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm unsure how to solve the following problem:

- I have a PyQT app which opens some child windows whenever you press a button
- I'm saving the reference to this pop-up window in my application class (`self.w` below)
- If I close the pop-up window, the variable `self.w` will still hold a reference to the closed window
- if somewhere in my code I call `self.w.repaint()` I get an error message `RuntimeError: underlying C/C++ object has been deleted`. This error is due to the fact that we still have a reference to the closed window stored in `self.w`.

**Question:**
How do I have to modify the code below, so that when the pop-up is closed, the attribute `self.w` is set to `None` automatically? What are good and poor ways of implementing this? The reason I want to set `self.w` to `None` is that I'll be able to check whether this attribute is `None` and in case it is, I can re-initalize a pop-up window before calling `repaint()` and thus avoiding the error message.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt4.Qt import *

class MyPopup(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        dc = QPainter(self)
        dc.drawLine(0, 0, 100, 100)
        dc.drawLine(100, 0, 0, 100)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, *args)
        self.cw = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.cw)
        self.btn1 = QPushButton("Click me", self.cw)
        self.btn1.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 100, 30))
        self.connect(self.btn1, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.doit)
        self.w = None

    def doit(self):
        print "Opening a new popup window..."
        self.w = MyPopup()
        self.w.setGeometry(QRect(100, 100, 400, 200))
        self.w.show()

class App(QApplication):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QApplication.__init__(self, *args)
        self.main = MainWindow()
        self.connect(self, SIGNAL("lastWindowClosed()"), self.byebye )
        self.main.show()

    def byebye( self ):
        self.exit(0)

def main(args):
    global app
    app = App(args)
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question:

> How do I have to modify the code below, so that when the pop-up is
>   closed, the attribute self.w is set to None automatically? What are
>   good and poor ways of implementing this?

You should try adding this in your popup class' init method:
`self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)`

You will find it in the docs here:
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#WidgetAttribute-enum

On retrospect, if a call on your self.w.repaint() throws that error `RuntimeError: underlying C/C++ object has been deleted`, it means that the object has actually been deleted. `self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)` will ensure that the object does get deleted on close. This is the cleanest way to do it.

Gathering from your comments, you want to cleanly free up your class property that holds this widget when this close event occurs. To do this, we can just have the popup emit a signal when it closes, that the main window can catch to do the freeing up. You can do this like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt4.Qt import *
from PyQt4 import QtCore

class MyPopup(QWidget):
    close_signal = pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        dc = QPainter(self)
        dc.drawLine(0, 0, 100, 100)
        dc.drawLine(100, 0, 0, 100)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.on_close()

    def on_close(self):
        """ Perform on close stuff here """
        self.close_signal.emit()


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, *args)
        self.cw = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.cw)
        self.btn1 = QPushButton("Click me", self.cw)
        self.btn1.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 100, 30))
        self.connect(self.btn1, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.doit)

        self.btn2 = QPushButton("repaint me", self.cw)
        self.btn2.setGeometry(QRect(100, 30, 200, 50))
        self.connect(self.btn2, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.repaintPopup)        

        self.w = None

    def doit(self):
        print "Opening a new popup window..."
        self.w = MyPopup()
        self.w.setGeometry(QRect(100, 100, 400, 200))
        self.w.show()
        self.w.close_signal.connect(self.on_popup_closed)

    def repaintPopup(self):
        self.w.repaint()

    def on_popup_closed(self):
        """ Cleanup the popup widget here """
        print "Popup closed."
        self.w = None


class App(QApplication):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QApplication.__init__(self, *args)
        self.main = MainWindow()
        self.connect(self, SIGNAL("lastWindowClosed()"), self.byebye )
        self.main.show()

    def byebye( self ):
        self.exit(0)


def main(args):
    global app
    app = App(args)
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

Here, though your Popup is a standalone widget without any parent. That is why it shows up as a window. If you want to maintain a parent child relationship, your popup would have to be a window (eg. QMainWindow) with the MyPopup QWidget as its central widget, and your main window set as the parent. This will ensure that this popup will always be treated as your main window's child, and lets the popup access the main window using the [nativeParentWidget()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#nativeParentWidget) method. To perform that change, you'd just have to refactor a little like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt4.Qt import *
from PyQt4 import QtCore

class MyPopup(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        dc = QPainter(self)
        dc.drawLine(0, 0, 100, 100)
        dc.drawLine(100, 0, 0, 100)


class PopupWindow(QMainWindow):
    close_signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, *args)
        self.cw = MyPopup(parent=self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.cw)
        self.setGeometry(QRect(100, 100, 400, 200))
        self.cw.setGeometry(QRect(100, 100, 400, 200))
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        print "I am the popup Window. My parent is: %s" % self.nativeParentWidget() # access the parent here

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        """ Perform on close stuff here """
        self.on_close()

    def on_close(self):
        self.close_signal.emit()

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, *args)
        self.cw = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.cw)
        self.btn1 = QPushButton("Click me", self.cw)
        self.btn1.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 100, 30))
        self.connect(self.btn1, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.doit)
        self.btn2 = QPushButton("repaint me", self.cw)
        self.btn2.setGeometry(QRect(100, 30, 200, 50))
        self.connect(self.btn2, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.repaintPopup)        
        self.w = None

    def doit(self):
        print "Opening a new popup window..."
        self.w = PopupWindow(self)
        self.w.show()
        self.w.repaint()
        self.w.close_signal.connect(self.on_popup_closed)

    def repaintPopup(self):
        self.w.repaint()

    def on_popup_closed(self):
        """ Cleanup the popup widget here """
        print "Popup closed."
        self.w = None

class App(QApplication):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QApplication.__init__(self, *args)
        self.main = MainWindow()
        self.connect(self, SIGNAL("lastWindowClosed()"), self.byebye )
        self.main.show()

    def byebye( self ):
        self.exit(0)

def main(args):
    global app
    app = App(args)
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

You can use the sip module's `isdeleted()` method to test if your object has infact been deleted. Just an extra check if you want to.

```
import sip
sip.isdeleted(self.w)
```

Check out more methods offered by the sip module for dealing with swig/C/C++ objects here: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/sip4/python_api.html

I hope that was useful.

Comment: Goes in the popup class' init. This will clear the reference. Do try it and let me know.

Comment: You get that error because the object HAS been successfully deleted. You will NOT get that error if the object still exists. So getting that error is probably what you want? If you don;t want that error, then you shouldnt try to repaint an object that has been deleted.

Comment: I have clarified these in my answer above. Please consider removing the downvote for an answer that is not wrong. Thank you.

Comment: again, I still get an error, because the program doesn't `see` that the window is closed and therefore the `repaint()` throws an error. As I say in my question, I want to get rid of this error. Your answer doesn't provide a solution. I want to get the attribute `self.w` to None when the popup is closed.

Comment: I am re drafting the answer for you. The code needs some changes from a design perspective. I will post it soon.

Comment: I have updated my answer with some pointers and suggestions. Hope you find it useful.

Comment: You can use the sip module's isdeleted() method to see if the object has infact been deleted. I have updated that in the answer